# How to catch all exceptions instantiating specific class?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to achieve an expressiveness in catching exceptions similar to Java/C#, where I can specify an interface of exceptions I want to catch, otherwise I need to enumerate all possible types.

```
interface I {void f();}
class AE extends Exception implements I {}
class BE extends Exception implements I {}
try {
  throw (new Random().next() % 2 == 0 
          ? new AE() 
          : new BE());   
} catch (I e) {
  e.f();
}
```

```
class I e where f :: e -> IO ()
data AE = AE deriving (Show)
data BE = BE deriving (Show)
instance Exception AE
instance Exception BE
instance I AE where f _ = putStrLn "f AE"
instance I BE where f _ = putStrLn "f BE"

run m = try @(forall e . (I e, Exception e) => e) m >>= \case
    Left er -> f er
    Right () -> pure ()
```

Compiler complains:

```
  GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
```

---

Original error is produced by ghc 8.10.7.

GHC 9.2.1 has been released.
With ImpredicitveTypes turned on the error is different:

```
    • No instance for (Exception (forall e. I e => e))
        arising from a use of ‘try’
```

Comment: As far as I know, the GHC runtime does not keep around any type class information that can be queried. Therefore, it's not possible to test whether a type belongs to a type class at runtime.

Comment: And as a rule of thumb it is _generally_ not possible to _test if_ a type belongs to a class. You can _require_ a type to belong to a class, and then failure will cause a compile-time error, but you can't have different behaviour based on whether or not a type belongs to a class. (That's not completely true, there are tricks for essentially checking for typeclass membership; but it's usually a bad idea to go that route.) What you should probably throw instead is something based around `data I = AE | BE`.

Comment: `data I = A|B` is not convenient because A and B originate from different modules and don't related to each other. Existentials are counter intuitive - more runtime data than normal value, but casting is available. Ok there is no types but there are method dictionaries - why "GHC" cannot check in runtime that dict has all keys specific for the specified class constraint?!

Comment: Typeclass dictionaries aren't, like, Python dicts where you _look up_ how each method is defined. That would be crazy slow. Instead, they're statically optimised tables where the compiler has arranged that everything required _is just there_.

Comment: Runtime values don't come with their method dictionaries embedded, like they do in Java, .NET, and every dynamically type language. In Haskell dictionaries are passed _alongside_ the values as extra parameters that are invisible to the programmer. So if all you have is a value, you can't look at its method dictionary.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, for general purpose it might not need and slow, but this is about catching exception, which are supposed to happen rarely. Is it worth of writing ghc proposal?

Comment: @DaneelYaitskov I strongly doubt this would get considered as a GHC proposal, especially seeing as the runtime-accessible combination of a value plus a relevant dictionary is exactly an existential, and GHC supports these already. But I agree that it's rather awkward for exceptions. Fortunately, [it seems to be possible to address that issue with a library](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/exception-via#readme).

Comment: ...hm, actually, going through that README it strikes me that we were all wrong – polymorphic exceptions _are_ already supported, though only with the weird `SomeException` trick, and that's in fact what the exception-via library is based on.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it's not a trick, it's just `Typeable`. `SomeException` is an existential around `Typeable`. Your answer was totally valid, just add a bit about `SomeException` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by **@leftaroundabout** (now deleted) was pretty good at explaining the basics, and I think it should be undeleted. But I am adding this answer to explain the "standard" GHC system of exceptions ([see also docs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.14/base-4.14.3.0/Control-Exception.html)).

First you have the `Exception` class, and all your exceptions should implement that. What you don't know is that when you throw an exception, it actually gets wrapped in `SomeException`, and it is that `SomeException` value that is actually thrown.

`SomeException` is defined as an existential wrapping the `Exception` class:

```
data SomeException where
  SomeException :: Exception e => e -> SomeException
```

And the wrapping happens via the `toException` method of the `Exception` class. In the code you posted, you're implementing the `Exception` instance without defining any methods, so the default implementations are used. And the default implementation of `toException` is just straight up wrapping:

```
toException e = SomeException e
```

**Q:** Ok, that's cool, but when I *catch* such exception, won't I just get a value of type `SomeException`? What's the use of that?

Ah, but that's only half the story! When you *catch* an exception, a reverse unwrapping happens: the `fromException` method unwraps the `SomeException` wrapper and then sees if the value inside matches the type you were trying to catch.

**Q:** Hold right there! "Sees if value matches the type"? Didn't you just say there was no runtime type information in Haskell?

Well, there is. Kinda. Only when you need it.

[It's called `Typeable`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.14/base-4.14.3.0/Data-Typeable.html). It's a magic class that you don't have to implement or derive, but GHC will make you an instance of it whenever you require. And it just so happens (well, it's actually on purpose) that the `Exception` class has `Typeable` as a superclass, meaning any type implementing `Exception` has to also implement `Typeable`. Except you don't have to actually *implement* `Typeable`, the compiler does it for you.

The only thing `Typeable` really allows to do is to get a sort of "type ID" - an opaque value that uniquely identifies a specific type. And then you can use those values to compare, and thus determine if a generic value you're given is of a specific type. This whole comparison + coercion business is wrapped neatly in a [function called `cast`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.14/base-4.14.3.0/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast). You give it a value and a target type, and it compares their "type IDs" obtained from `Typeable` (so both the value and the target type have to implement it), and then returns you the same value, but coerced to the target type. Or not, if it turns out to be of a different type. So it returns a `Maybe`.

And that's how the `SomeException` unwrapping basically happens in `fromException`, which is the second method of `Exception`:

```
fromException :: Exception e => SomeException -> Maybe e
fromException (SomeException x) = cast x
```

Remember: this happens every time you catch an exception. Basically the `catch` function calls `fromException`, then calls your handler if the result is `Just` (meaning the exception is of your type) or doesn't if it's `Nothing`.

**Q:** Ok, that's even cooler, but that doesn't solve my problem: do I really need to catch every single specific type of exception? Can't I catch them all at once somehow?

Yes, you can! You can use this whole framework to set up yourself a *hierarchy* of existentials. Say, we'd like a hierarchy that looks like this:

[image: hierarchy]

Just like in good ol' OOP! :-)

In order to do that, `MyException` would be another existential, just like `SomeException` itself:

```
data MyException where
  MyException :: forall e. Exception e => MyException

instance Exception MyException
```

Then you make sure that, during the "wrapping" process that happens when you throw an exception, both `AE` and `BE` get wrapped in `MyException` before getting wrapped in `SomeException`:

```
instance Exception AE where
  toException e = SomeException $ MyException e

-- Same implementation for BE
```

And similarly, when the "unwrapping" happens on catching, make sure both `AE` and `BE` can unwrap themselves by first making sure it's a `MyException` that is wrapped inside `SomeException`, and then that it's `AE` or `BE` respectively that is wrapped inside `MyException`:

```
instance Exception AE where
  fromException x = do
    MyException m <- cast x
    cast m

-- Same implementation for BE
```

Of course, doing it this way is a bit fragile: both `AE` and `BE` have to know not only their own "ancestor" type `MyException`, but also its ancestor type `SomeException`. So in practice both wrapping and unwrapping of `MyException` is usually delegated to `MyException`'s own `Exception` instance:

```
instance Exception AE where
  toException e = toException $ MyException e

  fromException x = do
    MyException m <- fromException x
    cast m
```

And voila: now you can catch either `AE` or `BE` individually or `MyException`, which would apply to them both. Why? Because if you're catching `MyException`, as `SomeException` gets unwrapped, the `MyException`'s implementation of `fromException` will be used for unwrapping. But if you're catching `AE`, then it's `AE`'s implementation of `fromException` that will be used, unwrapping `MyException` first and then `AE` itself.

**Q:** Ok, great, now I get all that, but still: can I query for the exception implementing a certain type class?

Yes and no.

If you just have an arbitrary value lying around, you cannot tell if it implements a certain type class, let's call it `I`. Because Haskell doesn't have runtime type information, unless you specifically asked for it, and even then, `Typeable` can only answer "is this value of type X?"

But it's even more than that: "*does this value implement class `I`?*" is not even a valid question, because it depends on scope. In modules where the `I` implementation module is imported, you do have such instance. In modules without such import, the instance doesn't exist. And you could even have *two different* instances of `I` for the same type, in different modules, which are imported in different parts of the program. Sure, it's a bad practice, don't do it, but it *can* happen.

The root of the problem here is that, unlike OOP interfaces, a class instance is not a property of the type itself, but a relationship between a type (or several types) and a class.

**But!** You still kinda can.

What you can do is require that any exception that "inherits" (see the diagram above) from `MyException` must have an instance of a certain class:

```
data MyException where
  MyException :: (Exception e, I e) => e -> MyException
```

Now anybody who wants to wrap a value inside `MyException` must provide an instance `I e`, and that instance will be wrapped inside the `MyException` value, and you'll get access to it when you unwrap it. For example:

```
class I a where 
  i :: a -> String

instance I AE where
  i _ = "This is AE"

throw AE `catch` \(MyException e) -> purStrLn (i e)
```

I can use the method `i` in the handler, because I just unwrapped `MyException` and got an `I` dictionary out of it.

But the important point is: the dictionary didn't come out of thin air. It was put inside the `MyException` value by whoever threw the exception in the first place.

---

A tangent: you can actually hijack (sort of) the exception wrapping/unwrapping mechanism to allow catching types that haven't been thrown. All you do is make a "dishonest" implementation of `fromException`:

```
data Hijacked = Hijacked deriving Show

instance Exception Hijacked where
  fromException x = do
    AE <- fromException x  -- See if it's an AE
    pure Hijacked

throw AE `catch` \Hijacked -> putStrLn "I caught a Hijacked!"
```

Answer (score 4):

*I'm undeleting this answer again, but please read [Fyodor Solkin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69783755/745903) first.*

---

As I already commented, this is probably the wrong approach entirely and you should instead be using a single exception type

```
data I = AE | BE ...
```

However, if you insist on having the open-type-class capability, this type can also be an existential (which is what OO references-to-base-class are, basically). Do note that [existentials should not be used](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) unless you really have a good reason for doing it that way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, LambdaCase, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Control.Exception


class I e where f :: e -> IO ()

data AE = AE deriving (Show)
instance I AE where f _ = putStrLn "f AE"
data BE = BE deriving (Show)
instance I BE where f _ = putStrLn "f BE"

data AnI where
  AnI :: (I e, Show e) => e -> AnI
deriving instance Show AnI
instance Exception AnI

run m = try m >>= \case
    Left (AnI er) -> f er
    Right () -> pure ()

main :: IO ()
main = run (throw (AnI BE))
```

The [exception-via](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/exception-via#readme) library seems to address the awkwardness of explicitly wrapping up these existentials, and to allow creating actual *hierarchies* of exceptions. I haven't tried the library yet, but it looks promising.

---

An alternative, which allows you to throw the types “raw” without a wrapper but on the flip side requires a priori listing all the supported exceptions (but literally just *listing* them), is

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax
           , MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, ConstraintKinds
           , AllowAmbiguousTypes
           , TypeApplications, RankNTypes, DeriveAnyClass, TypeOperators #-}

import Control.Exception
import Data.Kind


class PolyExcept (c :: Type -> Constraint) (l :: [Type]) where
  handleAll :: (∀ e . c e => e -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a

instance PolyExcept c '[] where
  handleAll _ = id

instance ∀ c e l . (Exception e, c e, PolyExcept c l)
            => PolyExcept c (e ': l) where
  handleAll h a = handle @e h (handleAll @c @l h a)

class I e where f :: e -> IO ()

data AE = AE deriving (Show, Exception)
instance I AE where f _ = putStrLn "f AE"
data BE = BE deriving (Show, Exception)
instance I BE where f _ = putStrLn "f BE"

run :: IO () -> IO ()
run = handleAll @I @'[AE, BE] f

main :: IO ()
main = run (throw BE)
```